# Pycharm Remote Interpreter from Docker using aws-glue-libs can't find relevant libraries

Tags: python, docker, pyspark, pycharm, aws-glue

I'm trying to prototype glue code locally as it is unnecessarily expensive to do this in the console or using development endpoints. I found that aws-glue-libs has a docker container that can be used for this purpose.

When I pull aws-glue-libs

```
docker pull amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01
```

and run spark-shell or jupytr lab i'm able to successfully import awsglue and pyspark.

However, I much prefer using Pycharm's IDE. So I attempted to use the docker image as a remote interpreter in pycharm, like so:

[interpreter set-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLsJ9.png)

[python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7MKk.png)

However, once the skelotons finish updating, it is not able to find the packages "awsglue" or "pyspark."

[package list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZfvk.png)

How can I fix this?

Pulled several image versions:

glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01
glue_libs_3.0.0_image_01
glue_libs_2.0.0_image_01
glue_libs_1.0.0_image_01

Same issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.